# Fluent API map composite pattern object

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, fluent-interface, composite-primary-key

I am trying to map a composite object using FluentAPI on entity framework 5.0 for the following model:

```
public class Category
{
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Category> Children { get; set; }
}
```

So far tried many ways that didn't work well, such as the following:

```
HasKey(t => t.CateroryId);
HasOptional(c => c.Children)
   .WithMany()
   .HasForeignKey(c => c.CateroryId);
```

Any idea how I might do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I've understood what you're going for - a `Category` is able to have many categories as children.

I've done this in the past using a similar foreign key mapping and some additional properties, although there may be a way to do it using independent association.

Adding additional properties to your `Category` so we can keep track of the parent/child relationship:

```
public class Page
{
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    public int? ParentID { get; set; } // Nullable (Parent is optional).

    // Navigation properties
    public virtual Category Parent { get; set; } // Optional Parent
    public virtual ICollection<Category> Children { get; set; }
}
```

You should then be able to configure like so (depending on where your mappings are set):

```
this.HasMany(c => c.Children)        // Many Children
    .WithOptional(c => c.Parent)     // Optional Parent
    .HasForeignKey(x => x.ParentID);
```